# Dictate order that operands are evaluated in c

Tags: c, operator-precedence

The statement `puts("a") + puts("b")` is undefined.
This is because it is not specified in the C Standard whether these ought to be executed left to right or right to left so you could get

```
a
b
```

or

```
b
a
```

Is there a clean way to dictate the order of operations in an expression?

The only thing I can think of is to use a compound statement such as

```
({
    int temp = puts("a");
    temp += puts("b");
    temp;
})
```

though this is non-portable and a little longer than I was hoping.

How could this best be achieved?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Use two statements, make your code readable.

Comment: Since all you're told about the return values is _The functions `fputs()` and `puts()` return a nonnegative integer on success and EOF on error_, there's no virtue whatsoever in adding the two results.  You need to choose a better motivating example.  But the long and the short of it is that you have to call the function twice in separate statements, as in your alternative.  But the testing needs to be different too.

Comment: The actual use case is a self made print function that recursively calls itself and sums up the number of characters written

Comment: @rtpax: why can't you split the calls into separate statements?

Comment: @chqrlie recursively wasn't exactly the right word, it uses a macro to do type checking with the _Generic keyword on a variable number of arguments. The end syntax is comparable to javas System.out.print()

Comment: `puts("a") + puts("b")` is not undefined. The order of calls is *unspecified*, but it must output either `a\nb\n` or `b\na\n`.

Comment: @M.M The end value is defined, but the console output is not. I understand that the value will be the same either way

Comment: @rtpax it's important to distinguish *undefined* from *unspecified*. If it were truly undefined then anything could happen, e.g. program crash. or output bananas

Comment: @M.M Maybe you are correct, though I am unsure. Either way there is _some_ function you could call that the behavior is undefined if called in this way

Comment: @rtpax: *I understand that the value will be the same either way* Not necessarily in the case of `puts()` as the return values may depend on the evaluation order... they may actually depend on just about anything as long as they are non negative on success. For example, `puts()` returns `rand()` on some DS9K systems, which I believe is conformant ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declare an `int` variable before the expression, you can force order portably with the comma operator while computing the sum inside an expression:

```
int temp;
...

(temp = puts("a"), temp + puts("b"))
```

As specified in the C Standard:

> **6.5.17 Comma operator**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
>  expression:
>      assignment-expression
>      expression , assignment-expression
> ```
>
> **Semantics**
>
> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

Note however that the value of the expression will not be very useful given the semantics of `puts()`, as commented by Jonathan Leffler.

Comment: This is correct, would you please add a mention of the [c standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (c11 section 6.5.17) where is specifies that the order of evaluation is left to right for completeness

Answer (score 1):

The only way to force the order of evaluation is to use separate statements.
Compilers can use whatever order is deemed necessary. So for function calls f1() + f2() + f3(); any of one of those function calls could be called before the other.  The only influence you can have on that statement is what to do with the returns from those functions. So in short, just use separate statements. Most likely for whatever you're doing, putting the calls in a loop should do fine.

Decent reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order